# Portlet is temporarily disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, portlet, websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I am getting "Portlet is temporarily disabled" after deploying portlet war through rational application developer into websphere portal server

Actually the process is developers develop the portlet and deploy into websphere portal server using rad. But when deploying it is ok deployed but while starting it is throwing some exceptions like `java.util.zipexception`, `servletexception` and some. If we check the status of the portlet it is in stopped status and if we access the portlet we are getting  "Portlet is temporarily disabled".

But if i deploy the portlet using websphere portal server console webmodule install is deploying and starting as expected

The environment is

```
-RedHat linux 6.5(64bit)
-websphere Portal server 8.0.0.1 (64bit)
-websphere application server 8.0.0.8 CF10
-Rational application developer 9.0.0
```

and it is a standalone env with only one profile wp_profile

and messages of the systemout.log file of  wp_profile is

```
[6/3/14 5:00:13:994 PDT] 00000034 SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.

[6/3/14 5:00:13:995 PDT] 00000034 SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.

[6/3/14 5:00:14:387 PDT] 00000034 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:

[6/3/14 5:00:23:680 PDT] 00000009 ApplicationMg A WSVR0220I: Application stopped: TestEAR

[6/3/14 5:00:36:787 PDT] 00000009 CompositionUn A WSVR0193I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=TestEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=TestEAR stopped.

[6/3/14 5:00:36:881 PDT] 00000007 AdminHelper A ADMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the TestEAR application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wpsadmin)

[6/3/14 5:00:37:187 PDT] 00000007 CompositionUn A WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=TestEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=TestEAR.

[6/3/14 5:00:37:401 PDT] 00000007 wtp I org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl loadDeploymentDescriptor EAR [ /root/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/TestEAR ] Module [ Test.war ] [

Web Module [ org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.impl.WebModuleImpl@54748181 ]

URI [ Test.war ]

Alt DD [ null ]

Context Root [ null ]

] handled as loose archive [ com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl@82c5df5f (URI: Test.war, lastModified: 0, size: 0, directoryEntry: , originalURI: Test.war) (types: null) ]

[6/3/14 5:00:37:669 PDT] 00000007 ApplicationMg A WSVR0200I: Starting application: TestEAR

[6/3/14 5:00:37:670 PDT] 00000007 ApplicationMg A WSVR0204I: Application: TestEAR Application build level: Unknown

[6/3/14 5:00:38:767 PDT] 00000007 webapp I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Test.

[6/3/14 5:00:38:997 PDT] 00000007 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host.Test

[6/3/14 5:00:39:102 PDT] 00000007 MBeanDescript I ADMN1216I: One or more methods in Portlet mbean is excluded from access check.

[6/3/14 5:00:39:106 PDT] 00000007 MBeanDescript I ADMN1216I: One or more methods in PortletApplication mbean is excluded from access check.

[6/3/14 5:00:39:261 PDT] 00000007 DefaultFacesC I Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml

[6/3/14 5:00:39:438 PDT] 00000007 DefaultFacesC I Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

[6/3/14 5:00:53:975 PDT] 00000007 AbstractFaces E An error occured while initializing MyFaces: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getClassloaderFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:275)

at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:101)

at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:457)

at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:343)

at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)

at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)

at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)

at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)

at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)

at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorService.invoke(RMIConnectorService.java:366)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:524)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:149)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:578)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1578)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3076)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2946)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)

at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:151)

at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:150)

at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:87)

at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.util.Classpath._getAlternativeJarFile(Classpath.java:302)

at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.util.Classpath._searchResource(Classpath.java:100)

at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:65)

at com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.resource.WASFacesConfigResourceProvider.getMetaInfConfigurationResources(WASFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:69)

at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getClassloaderFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:245)

... 65 more


[6/3/14 5:00:54:233 PDT] 00000007 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet

[6/3/14 5:00:54:253 PDT] 00000007 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}

javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:404)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1366)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:615)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:584)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:421)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)

at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)

at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)

at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorService.invoke(RMIConnectorService.java:366)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:524)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:149)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:578)

at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1578)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3076)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2946)

at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)

at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!

If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.

A typical config looks like this;


org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener



at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:196)

at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)

... 62 more


[6/3/14 5:00:54:271 PDT] 00000007 webcontainer I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module Test has been bound to default_host[*:9081,*:80,*:9444,*:5063,*:5062,*:443,*:10046,*:10049,*:10027,*:10025,*:10028,*:10039,*:10029,*:10032].

[6/3/14 5:00:54:409 PDT] 0000007b ObjectModelRe I com.ibm.wps.services.registry.ObjectModelRegistry registerWASPortletApplication EJPPG0024I: Web application with context root /.Test is deployed in the application server but not registered with portal.

[6/3/14 5:00:54:460 PDT] 00000007 ApplicationMg A WSVR0221I: Application started: TestEAR

[6/3/14 5:00:54:461 PDT] 00000007 CompositionUn A WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=TestEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=TestEAR started.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was that I installed portlet through WAS console, not through Portal Administration -> Web Modules. IF you install portlet with WAS, Portal do not start portlet application, if you install with Portal Web Modules you can start portlet immediately

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with context root in the file Test.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml file
the value is like "uri=.Test" but it should match with the war file name like this "uri=Test"
then repack the war and deploy, Now you can see the output message in the systemout.log file as "SystemOut o Login Name :: [uid= etc.,", Problem Solved